# magento connect manager extension not visible

Tags: magento

Magento extensions installed by another team and they are not reachable now. When we checked files, we identify there are few extensions installed. But we couldn't see any extensions in Magento connect and also clicked 'check for upgrades' but its not showing any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions might be installed directly via ftp/shell and not via MagentoConnect. In that case, the extension is not mentioned in MagentoConnect.

Probably, in the config file of the module, the version number is added, so you can check if this is the most recent release.

If you want to upgrade to a newer version, you can simply copy and override these files to your shell to upgrade the module.